# How do I pass an array from a controller into blade in laravel using javascript

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel

I am trying to pass an array to javascript in view Laravel, I tried several answers I found on the internet but it doesn't work. Here's my controller code:

```
 $data=DB::table("tb_trx_perhitungan_bunga_simpanan")
        ->selectRaw('trx_bulan')
        ->get();  
  return view('crud.form.cobaNampilin',compact('data'));
```

and then this is my javacript and jquery in blade view

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var a;
        var array = {{!! json_encode($data) !!}};
        var i;
        var b;
        $('#bulan').keyup(function(){
        var bayar=parseInt($('#bulan').val());
            for(a=0;a<=array;a++){
                if(bayar==array[a]){
                    i=1;
                }
                else{
                    i=0;
                }
            }
         $('#hasil').val(i);
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Can we clarify what "doesn't work" means? What _does_ happen? Is there no data in the view at all, or is it the wrong data? Are there any errors?

Comment: it doesn't show anything, it doesn't show 1 or 0

Comment: I think it should show 1 or 2 depend on value input from variable bayar

Comment: Can you tell if the data is making it to the view at all? Do you see it if you view the page source? Any errors in the console?

Comment: when I try to show data in view with @foreach it shows the data, but when I try to use it in javascript in view it doesn't show anything

Comment: I think this is a typo: `{{!! json_encode($data) !!}}` should be `{!! json_encode($data) !!}`

Comment: yeah it work but why it shows [object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object],[object Object], how to choose an object in javascript? in view I usually use -> to point an object

Comment: convert that first to an array before passing to the view

Comment: can u tell me how to convert an object to array? , ive tries several code like Object.keys but it doesn't work

Comment: Try using the collections `toJson()` method instead: `{!! $data->toJson() !!}`.